# Displaying ampersand in as literal value

Tags: sql-server

I have a field where some values contain an ampersand.  When viewing the data in the table it displays properly.  When I run a query that selects this field it displays incorrectly.  Ex.  `36 & 38` returns as `36 &amp; 38`

How can I format this value to return the ampersand as a literal value?

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: When you say "it returns as", where exactly are you showing it? SQL Server won't change this at all, it's likely in your front end.

Comment: The only way SQL Server would transform `&` into `&amp;` is if you explicitly converted a value into XML (`FOR XML PATH` and the like). If your query doesn't contain the word "XML", the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @JeroenMostert has the right point here. Characters such as `&`, `<`, `>`, etc, etc aren't legal characters in xml, thus are replaced by SQL Server when using `FOR XML PATH` to `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc. If you eed to change this back, you have to use `REPLACE`. Thus `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,'&amp;','&'),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>')`

Answer (score 0):

@JeroenMostert and @Larnu were correct about the XML.  Looking back at the data I was pulling from a view that converted the value to XML.  After changing the select to

```
REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,'&amp;','&)
```

I got the output I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `&amp;` is not the only character entity. A safer alternative is `column.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`, or some variation thereof, depending on what the column actually contains (incorporating this in the view may be an even better idea, if it's naively using `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate strings). Note also that if the column actually *is* XML, replacing entities like this will result in invalid markup. It may look nice, but it's not what systems that want the result as XML will be expecting.